# What are the differences between 2011 and 2012 samsung smartTV emulators?

Tags: emulation, samsung-smart-tv

Where can I read about that?

I wrote samsung smartTV application, but there are some errors in 2011 emulator. 
Thank you! Sorry for my language.

Answer (score 1):

You can see TV/emulator specifications [here](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Spec). Main differences are:

- DOM's level (2 vs. 3)
- JavaScript engine (Javascript 1.8 vs. SquirrelFish)

As far as I know web browser's engine was changed too, but I'm not sure if it was between 2011 and 2012. However, Gecko was used other day, now is Webkit.